# delete rows having more than a day old date in csv file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

Noob question.
I have a csv file with the following format

```
2019-04-18 08:29:47,ACE001P,QL.IN.XCENTER.ERECEIPT.FACADE,2
```

The date and time stamp goes back almost a month. Now I only want data for the last day's date, means 1 day old data. I am using below code, but it gives me no output.

```
$Data = Import-CSV "E:\Chayan\QL.IN.XCENTER.ERECEIPT.FACADE_ACE001P_1.csv"
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -lt $CutoffDate} | Out-File .\QL.IN.XCENTER.ERECEIPT.FACADE_ACE001P_2.csv
```

I know I am doing something extremely stupid. Just need a way to make this work.

Comment: I don't see any headers in your CSV file. You need a Date header in order to access the date property (`$_.Date`). `(Get-Date).AddDays(-30)` should also be `(Get-Date).AddDays(-1)` for one day old data.

Answer (score 2):

In order to use `Import-Csv` effectively, you need headers in your data. I used the `-Header` switch and added made up headers that include `Date`. Feel free to change those. It can be omitted entirely if your file already has headers.

```
$Data = Import-CSV "E:\Chayan\QL.IN.XCENTER.ERECEIPT.FACADE_ACE001P_1.csv" -Header "Date","Col2","Col3","Col4"
$CutoffDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-30)
$Data | Where-Object {$_.Date -as [datetime] -gt $CutoffDate} |
   Export-Csv -Path ".\QL.IN.XCENTER.ERECEIPT.FACADE_ACE001P_2.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I switched the `-lt` to `-gt` because you are giving the low end of the date range. This means you need to find a date greater than that, i.e. today is greater than yesterday.

I left `.AddDays(-30)` as your date starter even though the post says you want one day old data. That should be changed to `.AddDays(-1)` or `.AddHours(-24)` if you really want data within the last day.